# Authentication middleware not working in Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I have the following routes and the session setup:

```
func SetupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()

    // Session
    store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
    // Set session expiration time
    store.Options(sessions.Options{MaxAge: 3600 * 24}) // 24hr
    r.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))

    r.GET("api/business/", controllers.GetBusiness)
    r.POST("api/business/login", controllers.Login)
    r.GET("api/business/logout", controllers.Logout)
    r.GET("api/business/session", controllers.GetBusinessSession)
    r.POST(
        "api/itemcategory/add", 
        // isBusinessAuth(), 
        controllers.CreateItemCategory,
    )
    r.POST(
        "api/itemcategory/delete/:id",
        // isBusinessAuth(),
        controllers.DeleteItemCategory,
    )
    r.GET(
        "api/itemcategory/all",
        // isBusinessAuth(),
        controllers.GetAllItemCategories,
    )
    r.POST(
        "api/itemcategory/update/:id",
        // isBusinessAuth(),
        controllers.CreateItemCategory,
    )

    return r
}
```

the `isBusinessAuth()` function:

```
func isBusinessAuth() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if sessions.Default(c).Get("businessAuth") == 1 {
            c.Next()
            return
        } else {
            c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": "You are not authorized!"})
        }
        c.Abort()
        return
    }
}
```

This is how session is placed, in the Login function:

```
// Set business session
session.Set("businessAuth", 1)
session.Save()
```

No matter what value has the session, `isBusinessAuth()` is returning "You are not authorized" for all the routes where is used. I tried to put it on "/api/business/login" and "/api/business/session" routes and there is working as expected. What am I missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: Obvious question: how is "businessAuth" placed into the context? What is sessions.Default?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: How is `session` placed into the context? Where is it stored between calls?

Comment: I don't think I understand your questions properly. Isn't the sessions stored global? I am using this: https://github.com/gin-contrib/sessions for the session

Comment: That was where I was going. Is that library storing your sessions? If not, each call is separate and you cannot preserve state. You have to store that session either in a cookie, or some other storage, which may include a global variable.

Comment: is strange because for all the routes in the business.go package, the session persists (I put some prints), but in itemcategory.go, is not. thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

This requires the client to be able to save cookies, which you can test using Chrome

Session communication is generally realized through cookie. Different from cookie, session only saves a sessionID on the client. Unlike cookie, specific data of session is only saved on the server instead of the client

In Servlet, session data is encapsulated in an object, which will be stored in the object pool. When the client makes a request, it will bring its sessionID, and the server will obtain the corresponding session object from the object pool according to this sessionID. Obtains session data from the object. The server uses this session data to maintain or change the state of the session with the client.

When accessing the server, the client checks whether the client request data contains a SessionID. If not, the client is considered to be accessing the server for the first time

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.